# LogoUI+<CheckServer>c__Iterator2.MoveNext () (Unity)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am working on a big project right now so what i am doing is converting the .exe application to .apk application and fortunately i successfully converted it somehow there's an error:

The whole error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>                                               at LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject[ServerListJson] (System.String json) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                               at LogoUI+c__Iterator2.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 
>                                               at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in :0

So I'm suspecting that the error above is in the logoUI.cs only.

Am i calling it wrong. Can someone point out whats wrong on what i am doing.

## LogoUI.cs

```
void TryShowIntro()
{
  StartCoroutine("CheckVersion");
}

IEnumerator CheckVersion()
{
    lbl_notification.text = NOTIFICATION[0];
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => tzGlobal.Instance.VERSION != null);
    FadeInVersion(tzGlobal.Instance.VERSION);

    StartCoroutine("CheckServer");
}

IEnumerator CheckServer()
{
    lbl_notification.text = NOTIFICATION[1];

    // Load the URL.
    CheckJSonManager.Instance._AwsDatacenterURL.SetURL();

    // Download the notice.
    WWW www = new WWW(CheckJSonManager.Instance._AwsDatacenterURL.NOTICE_URL);
    yield return www;

    // Save notice.
    StreetUtility.SaveJson_mk2(www.text, string.Format("{0}/notice.json", Application.streamingAssetsPath));

    // Download server list.
    www = new WWW(CheckJSonManager.Instance._AwsDatacenterURL.SERVERLIST_URL);
    yield return www;

    // Store server list.
    CheckJSonManager.Instance._ServerListJSon = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<ServerListJson>(www.text);

    // Server information to be connected is stored separately.
    bool bFound = false;
    ServerListJson pServerListJSon = CheckJSonManager.Instance._ServerListJSon;
    int target_server_no = System.Int32.Parse(tzGlobal.Instance.VERSION.Split('.')[2]);
    for (int i = 0; i < pServerListJSon.serverData.Length; i++)
    {
        if (target_server_no == pServerListJSon.serverData[i].serverNo)
        {
            bFound = true;
            ServerData pServerList = pServerListJSon.serverData[i];

            NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.SESSION_NAME = pServerList.serverNo.ToString();
            NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.SESSION_IP = pServerList.serverIP;
            NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.SESSION_PORT = pServerList.serverPort;
            tzGlobal.Instance.LOGIN_URL = pServerList.publisherURL;
            tzGlobal.Instance.JOIN_URL = pServerList.joinURL;
            tzGlobal.Instance.STREAMING_URL = pServerList.streamingURL;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!bFound)
    {
        // Debug.LogWarning("ServerList_mk2.json does not find the required server number. Use the first server information.");
        Debug.LogWarning("pc_version / ph / check / serverList.json does not find the required server number. Use the first server information.");


        ServerData pServerList = pServerListJSon.serverData[0];

        NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.SESSION_NAME = pServerList.serverNo.ToString();
        NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.SESSION_IP = pServerList.serverIP;
        NetworkManager.Instance.WebSocketServer.SESSION_PORT = pServerList.serverPort;
        tzGlobal.Instance.LOGIN_URL = pServerList.publisherURL;
        tzGlobal.Instance.JOIN_URL = pServerList.joinURL;
        tzGlobal.Instance.STREAMING_URL = pServerList.streamingURL;
    }

    // Auto-connect after a while.
    StartCoroutine("GoToLoginSceneAutomatically");
    EnableSkip("auto");
}
```

What i tried so far is this.

1.) I print out.

- `Debug.Log("www notice url= " + CheckJsonManager.Instance._AwsDatacenterURL.NOTICE_URL);`

Output

> jar:file:///data/app/com.steet383.rh.google-1/base.apk!/assets/notice.json

- `Debug.Log("www serverlist url= " + CheckJSonManager.Instance._AwsDatacenterURL.SERVERLIST_URL);`

Output

> jar:file:///data/app/com.steet383.rh.google-1/base.apk!/assets/serverList.json

Now this line of code

```
// Save the server list.
   CheckJSonManager.Instance._ServerListJSon = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<ServerListJson>(www.text);
```

has the error of this

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject[ServerListJson] (System.String json) [0x00000] in :0 at LogoUI+c__Iterator2.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in :0

It works on **UNITY_STANDALONE** but when i tried to change the platform to **UNITY_ANDROID** this line gives me the error. Is this code

`CheckJSonManager.Instance._ServerListJSon = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<ServerListJson>(www.text);`

not suitable for android??

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Does the download succeed? (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))

Comment: it is a success i guess cause it returns the serverlist and notice url when i print it out @MikkoKoivisto

Comment: ok. if www.text != null then NullReferenceException culprit must be some other object referenced on that line.

Comment: The error `at LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject[ServerListJson] (System.String json) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 - SOLVED` now the only error left is `object reference is not set` and I fixed it by using this `StreetUtility.SaveJson_mk2(www.text, string.Format("{0}/serverList.json", Application.streamingAssetsPath));` the problem i guess was the CheckJsonManager code wasn't suitable for mobile @MikkoKoivisto